# CQRS projections, joining data from different aggregates via probe commands

Tags: cqrs, saga, event-driven-design

In CQRS when we need to create a custom-tailored projections for our read-models, we usually prefer a "denormalized" projections (assume we are talking about projecting onto a DB). It is not uncommon to have the information need by the application/UI come from different aggregates (possibly from different BCs).

Imagine we need a projected table to contain customer's information together with her full address and that `Customer` and `Address` are different aggregates in our system (possibly in different BCs). Meaning that, addresses are generated and maintained independently of customers. Or, in other words, when a new customer is created, there is no guarantee that there will be an `AddressCreatedEvent` *subsequently* produced by the system, this event may have already been processed prior to the creation of the customer. All we have at the time of `CreateCustomerCommand` is an UUID of an existing address.

We have several solutions here.

1. Enrich `CreateCustomerCommand` and the subsequent `CustomerCreatedEvent` to contain full address of the customer (looking up this information on the fly from the UI or the controller). This way the projection handler will just update the table directly upon receiving `CustomerCreatedEvent`.
2. Use the `addrUuid` provided in `CustomerCreatedEvent` to perform an ad-hoc query in the projection handler to get the missing part of the address information before updating the table.

These are commonly discussed solution to this problem. However, as noted by many others, there are problems with each approach. Enriching events can be difficult to justify as well described by Enrico Massone [in this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/380160/how-to-model-domain-events-so-that-the-denormalizers-can-fill-highly-denormalize), for example. Querying other views/projections (kind of JOINs) will work but introduces coupling (see the same link).

I would like describe another method here, which, as I believe, nicely addresses these concerns. I apologize beforehand for not giving a proper credit if this is a known technique. Sincerely, I have not seen it described elsewhere (at least not as explicitly).

"A picture speaks a thousand words", as they say:

[image: CQRS joining data in projections via probe commands]

The idea is that :

1. We keep `CreateCustomerCommand` and `CustomerCreatedEvent` simple with only `addrUuid` attribute (no enriching).
2. In API controller we send **two commands** to the command handler (aggregates): the first one, as usual, - `CreateCustomerCommand` to create customer and project customer information together with `addrUuid` to the table leaving other columns (full address, etc.) empty for time being. (*Warning*: See the update, we may have concurrency issue here and need to issue the probe command from a Saga.)
3. Right after this, and after we have obtained `custUuid` of the newly created customer, we issue a special `ProbeAddrressCommand` to `Address` aggregate triggering an `AddressProbedEvent` which will encapsulate the full state of the address together with the special attribute `probeInitiatorUuid` which is, of course our `custUuid` from the previous command.
4. The projection handler will then act upon `AddressProbedEvent` by simply *filling in* the missing pieces of the information in the table looking up the required row by matching the provided `probeInitiatorUuid` (i.e. `custUuid`) and `addrUuid`.

So we have two phases: create `Customer` and probe for the related `Address`. They are depicted in the diagram with (1) and (2) correspondingly.

Obviously, we can send as many such "probe" commands (in parallel) as needed by our projection: `ProbeBillingCommand`, `ProbePreferencesCommand`, etc. effectively populating or "filling in" the denormalized projection with missing data from each handled "probe" event.

The advantages of this method is that we keep the commands/events in the first phase simple (only UUIDs to other aggregates) all the while avoiding synchronous coupling (joining) of the projections. The whole approach has a nice EDA feeling about it.

My question is then: is this a known technique? Seems like I have not seen this... And what can go wrong with this approach?

I would be more then happy to update this question with any references to other sources which describe this method.

**UPDATE 1**:

There is one significant flaw with this approach that I can see already: command `ProbeAddrressCommand` *cannot be issued before* the projection handler had a chance to process `CustomerCreatedEvent`. But this is impossible to know from the API gateway (or controller).

The solution would probably involve a Saga, say `CustomerAddressJoinProjectionSaga` with will start upon receiving `CustomerCreatedEvent` and which will only then issue `ProbeAddrressCommand`. The Saga will end upon registering `AddressProbedEvent`. Or, if many other aggregates are involved in probing, when all such events have been received.

So here is the updated diagram.

[image: issue probe from Saga]

**UPDATE 2**:

As noted by Levi Ramsey (see answer below) my example is rather convoluted with respect to the choice of aggregates. Indeed, `Customer` and `Address` are often conceptualized as belonging together (same Aggregate Root). So it is a better illustration of the problem to think of something like `Student` and `Course` instead, assuming for the sake of simplicity that there is a straightforward relation between the two: a student is taking a course. This way it is more obvious that `Student` and `Course` are independent aggregates (students and courses can be created and maintained at different times and different places in the system).

But the question still remains: how can we obtain a projection containing the full information about a student (full name, etc.) and the courses she is registered for (title, credits, the instructor's full name, prerequisites, etc.) all in the same table, if the UI requires it ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

I question why address needs to be a separate aggregate much less in a different bounded context, in view of the requirement that customers have an address.  If in some other bounded context customer addresses are meaningful (e.g. you want to know "which addresses have more customers" etc.), then that context can subscribe to the events from the customer service.

As an alternative, if there's a particularly strong reason to model addresses separately from customers, why not have the read side prospectively listen for events from the address aggregate and store the latest address for a given address UUID in case there's a customer who ends up with that address.  The reliability per unit effort of that approach is likely to be somewhat greater, I would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the input. See the update (2) with regards to the choice of aggregates... It's not really important, since combining data from _any two aggregates_ (in projections) is a common task in CQRS. As far, as I could gather, the projections exist to provide a convenient, ready-to-use support for the UI. If the UI mandates a single table where each line is in the form: `custUuid`, `custName`, `addrUuid`, `addrFull` (and no assumptions can be made about the sequence of related events, i.e. `CustCreatedEvt`, `AddrCreatedEvt`), how can we do this.

Comment: The problem with maintaining the read-model for the all the addresses (so that we can just look up the full address at the time the projection handler reacts to `CustCreatedEvt`) is that we would have to tie together two projections: `CustAddrProjTable`, the one we actually need, and the supporting `AddrProjTable`, which is there just to furnish the `addrFull`. We would have to first do a `SELECT addrFull` from the latter and then do an `INSERT` into the former. And we should avoid JOINing like this different projections, since they need to stay independent for facilitating the rebuild.